# robocopy /xd ignores a list of directories

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am putting together a Powershell script that syncs a source code tree into another directory. It creates a list of directories to ignore, per the output of `robocopy /?`:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Source file directories
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$reactjs = "C:\Users\me\Projects\prj\reactjs"

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Target directories
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$synergy = "C:\Users\me\Projects\sync\reactjs"
$synReactjs = $synergy + "\prj-JS"

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Directories to be ignored
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$reactIgnores = @(
  $reactjs + "\.git",
  $reactjs + "\node_modules",
  $reactjs + "\build"
)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copy/sync files
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Robocopy /l $reactjs $synReactjs /mir /xd $reactIgnores
```

However, robocopy immediately descends into the `.git` directory, though the output header looks like it parsed my switches correctly:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Wednesday, October 31, 2018 12:00:32 PM
   Source : C:\Users\me\Projects\prj\reactjs\
     Dest : C:\Users\me\Projects\sync\reactjs\prj-JS\

    Files : *.*

 Exc Dirs : C:\Users\me\Projects\prj\reactjs\.git C:\Users\me\Projects\prj\reactjs\node_modules C:\Users\me\Projects\prj\reactjs\build

  Options : *.* /L /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /Z /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          New Dir          8    C:\Users\me\Projects\prj\reactjs\
            New File                 634        .eslintrc.json
            New File                 206        .gitignore
            New File                  55        .npmrc
            New File              521255        package-lock.json
            New File                1015        package.json
            New File                1001        package.json.react16
            New File               10391        README
            New File                1639        README.md
          New Dir          9    C:\Users\me\Projects\prj\reactjs\.git\
            New File                 135        COMMIT_EDITMSG
            New File                 319        config
            New File                  73        description
            New File                 125        FETCH_HEAD
<...>
```

What am I missing with the `/xd` switch? It works fine with a single directory.

Edit: I included the Powershell tag because `/xd` ignores the list of files if I include them in the command line explicitly. Loading them via the array does not work. This results in an exc line of (compare to above):

```
 Exc Dirs : C:\Users\me\Projects\prj\reactjs\.git
            C:\Users\me\Projects\prj\reactjs\node_modules
            C:\Users\me\Projects\prj\reactjs\build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
$reactIgnores = @(
  $reactjs + "\.git",
  $reactjs + "\node_modules",
  $reactjs + "\build"
)
```

try putting the full path.

Comment: Interesting. That worked. Now why is that any different than the string assembly?

Comment: In your variable, $reactjs = "C:\Users\me\Projects\prj\reactjs" - you already have quotes around the path. Then in $reactjs + "\.git", there are quotes around the directory so PowerShell is seeing it as C:\Users\me\Projects\prj\reactjs \.git (there is a space between reactjs and \.git)

Comment: I don't see that space in the original `Exc Dirs` output from robocopy (in my original post)? Still, it does work now, which helps!

Answer (score 0):

This array worked for me, escaping double quotes with single quotes.  You don't need the full path and I used a single /XD $eXcludeDirectories command:

```
$eXcludeDirectories = @(
    '"Folder01"',
    '"Folder02"',
    '"Folder03"'
)
```

Hopefully this will help someone else.